# Android best way to make reel appear to spin

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a simple fruit machine / slot machine for Android.
I'm thinking how I can make the "reel" appear to spin, then gradually stop.

The way I was thinking was to have a surround, and then have images randomly generated at the top, moving down the screen. Only part of the image would be visible.

Any help with ideas, or how it can be done, would be absolutely fantastic!

I followed a tutorial online here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-achieving-movement/

This showed me how to extend surface view and create a class with movement. All I need to be able to do is find how to put that into my relativelayout, with the correct size depending on the phone, so it fits into my layout instead of the static image which currently is in it's place.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a very good 3rd party open source project called [Android Wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) that pretty much does everything involved in creating a slot machine for you. And if you want to customise it, it's under an Apache licence, so no issues there.

Comment: I think you may well be my hero for this. Looking into it now, it looks like this is going to be hugely helpful. Marking as answer.

Comment: Cool. Glad to help - I think it's a great library

Comment: I already marked this as the correct answer. I just wanted to get back to you and say thanks again, it's working perfectly and has helped me out endlessly. It's a really great library, and is really straight forwards to extend.

Comment: well, if you like it that much, you could always upvote :) But I guess the authors deserve more credit than me!!

Comment: Just as an update, looks like someone has ported this to Github: https://github.com/maarek/android-wheel