# Set background for items in a spinner using a drawable resource - java android studio

Tags: java, android, spinner

I've created a spinner using the code below. Now I want to use a drawable resource called circle.xml, to set the background for each item in the spinner so that each number appears inside a circle.

```
        Spinner equationSpinner = new Spinner(this);

        ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("");
        spinnerArray.add("1");
        spinnerArray.add("2");
        spinnerArray.add("3");
        spinnerArray.add("4");
        spinnerArray.add("5");

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        equationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

I can use the circle as a background in a TextView so I tried creating the spinnerArray as an array of TextViews but that appeared to be incompatible with the simple_spinner_dropdown_item. 
Anybody have an idea how I can do this? I just want each number to appear inside a circle in the spinner. I will also need to be able to access the number selected in the spinner.
Thanks

P.S. Is there any way in Android to create a 'slot machine' style spinner like you have in iOS? I prefer the look of those.

EDIT:
I've now found that I can use my circle resource by creating a custom layout (called spinner_item.xml) like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="28dip"
    android:layout_height="28dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

I then set the adapter for my spinner programmatically like this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.equations, R.layout.spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        equationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, this method requires that I have a predefined string array set up in my strings.xml file (R.array.equations). I need to be able to specify the array of strings to be used programmatically depending on the state of the app. Can I modify the array once its set up?

EDIT 2:
Additionally I've found I can set the background of the dropdown items and use my own programmatical array like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        equationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

The only problem then is being able to apply the resource to the background of the spinner itself (not the drop down items). There does not appear to be an equivalent to setDropDownViewResource for the main spinner item.

Comment: wouldn't it be easy if you  customize your spinner, then you can do what you want with it

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know how. I'm new to android and trying a few things. No success yet. If you are able to show me how it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

lets say `textview_background.xml` is the background you want to give to the textView to `Spinner`

make a file in drawable and name it this `textview_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
<corners android:radius="7dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@android:color/tertiary_text_light" />
</shape>
```

make a `Spinner` in your activity

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerOneActivity_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

make a layout with name `list_text_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:padding="4dp"
android:text="some"
android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

make a class which will fill data from a list to your spinner, in this code your Adapter class is taking list of String but you can have your own custom object list given to it to populate the spinner, watch out how adapter's constructor parameters.

first-`Context`

Second-`layout which will be given to each item in spinner`

Third-`a textView id from the above layout`

Forth-`your list of objects which you want to populate`

`TestAdapter.java`

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> strings;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public TestAdapter(Context context, int resource,int id, ArrayList<String> strings) {
    super(context, resource, id, strings);
    this.context = context;
    this.strings = strings;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_text_view, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textView.setText("" + strings.get(position));
    return view;
}
}
```

in your activity you can write this code

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("Two");
    list.add("Three");
    list.add("four");
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerOneActivity_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_text_view, R.id.text1,list));
```

As you wanted you can increase the list or generate things dynamically to add or remove from the list once your list is attached to adapter which will be provided to Spinner you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter to updated the list

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. In my last 2 edits I am almost there - just a small different part missing in each case. Is there a simply change I can make in either case to achieve what I need rather than making the big changes you suggested?

Comment: yes off course, you can do that. but that way you can only be able to change the textBackground and some little tweaks that's all

Comment: In my EDIT 2 I just have to set the background of the main spinner (selected item). I can't figure out how to do it. Are you able to help?

Comment: sorry @SteveW, you can't see expected change by directly applying background to spinner, that will change spinner background, you would have to implement some more changes, let me see if i can easy your work

Comment: Almost there now. equationSpinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle); gives me the background on the spinner but its the wrong shape. It should show as a circle but its elongated (oval) to the height of the spinner. Can I change the dimensions of the spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer about [Android Wheel](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503372/3677394

> There's a very good 3rd party open source project called Android Wheel
>   that pretty much does everything involved in creating a slot machine
>   for you. And if you want to customise it, it's under an Apache
>   licence, so no issues there.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10202366)

Comment: Agree, that's why I linked Anroid Wheel in comment :)